# Segmentation fault, no matter on how i change the code C++

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

this is my code

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

bool endsWith(string const &value, string const &ending)
{
    if(value.length() >= ending.length())
    {
        return (value.compare(value.length() - ending.length(), ending.length(), ending) == 0);
    }

    return false;
}

void listdir(const char *directory, const char *extension)
{
    DIR *dir;

    struct dirent *entry;

    if(!(dir = opendir(directory)))
    {
        return;
    }

    while(entry = readdir(dir))
    {
        if(entry->d_type == DT_DIR)
        {
            char path[1024];

            int len = snprintf(path, sizeof(path)-1, "%s/%s", directory, entry->d_name);

            path[len] = 0;

            if(strcmp(entry->d_name, ".") != 0 && strcmp(entry->d_name, "..") != 0)
            {
                listdir(path, extension);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            string file = entry->d_name;

            if(endsWith(file, strcat((char *) ".", extension)) || extension == "*")
            {
                printf("%s \n", entry->d_name);
            }
        }
    }

    closedir(dir);
}

int main(int count, char *parameters[])
{
    const char *type = "*";
    const char *path = ".";

    if(count > 1)
    {
        path = parameters[1];
    }

    if(count > 2)
    {
        type = parameters[2];
    }

    if(count < 1 || count > 3)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    listdir(path, type);

    return 0;
}
```

And no matter, what i am doing, i always receive segmentation fault.

Compiling it with g++ under debian is no problem, but running the application puts out always "Segmentation fault"

So what's the matter?

Comment: Error location? And you should decide for one language. Even your includes are in three different kinds

Comment: If you compile it with debugging, `g++ -g`, see if it gives you a line number or stack trace. If you run it through gdb, `gdb myfile`, does it tell you where it's halting?

Comment: You can use `valgrind` to see where it happens exactly, combined with a `-g` flag added to the compilation process.

Comment: A good way to avoid such problems is to use a suitable string class throughout.

Comment: Are you kidding: string::compare returns a value < 0, 0 or > 0, strcat((char *) ".", extension) is plain wrong, and there might be other issues

Comment: Other issues, like which? I'm sorry, i am all new to this. But i am learning hard!! :-)

Answer (score 3):

Your error lies in the line `strcat((char *) ".", extension)`, where you try to write data to the memory underlying a string literal.

String literals are loaded into a read only memory segment and trying to write to that causes your segfault.

If you wish to use `strcat`, you have to provide a target buffer of sufficient size (which is not checked, so using [`strncat`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncat/) is often preferred). Since this size is undetermined at compile time, you are forced to compute the length of the two strings you wish to append to one another and allocate a buffer of sufficient size with `new` or `malloc`.

However, the easiest way of performing a string concatenation in C++ is to forget all about the C equivalents and simply use `::std::string` like so:

```
::std::string s = "hello ";
s += "world";
```

Comment: Oh ok, yah that's it. So how can i set the point to the beginning of "extension" anyway?

Comment: I see, but backwards does it work? Like std::string s = "world"; s = "hello " + world; ?

Comment: Ok, well, in my case "extension" is a pointer to a char array. How can i set a point to the beginning in this case?

Comment: You promised not to change the characters `extension` points to by calling them `char const`. You will have to place the result of your computation in a new buffer. I suggest that you read my answer and formulate another question if you have more.